# Apache stanbol content extraction not working as expected

Tags: java, apache, nlp, apache-stanbol

I am trying to extract phrases using Apache Stanbol. I expect results as follows.

content="I live in Paris and would like to learn natural language processing using java."
extracted phrase should be,
**Paris

Natural Language Processing

Java**

But Its giving only **Paris**. I am using .....:8080/enhancer as endpoint.

my environment is ubuntu 12.10 /java

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer to my own question.

localhost:8080/enhancer endpoint uses the **default** chain which contain limited set of engines. The endpoint which gives me the expected result is localhost:8080/enhancer/chain/all-active and it uses the **all-active** chain which contain all active engines.

The best approach should be creating a custom chain which contains only required engines. I haven’t try this option.